# Build Interactive Floor With Projection?

Tags: c#, java, c++, apache-flex, actionscript-3

Dear Guys 
I am somehow newbie and sometimes guru , but at this moment i don't have enough time to research

My nightmare is , my boss ask me to create an interactive floor ( he just saw in an exhibition ) , he ask me to create one of them instead of buying , i am an actionscript crawler and developer with some skills in java and c# programming , i just made some track motion with a simple web cam , and this idea came to my mind if i can use an infrared or thermographic camera instead of simple camera so i can get better positioning if camera place at top of floor !

Now i just came here to ask you guys is there any resource , tip , help i can know before getting into this deal !?

is there any lib or api out to deal with this ?!
EVEN, if there is any resource , article from another language c++ , c , .... could help 
i just didn't have enough time to test lot of ways

If you search interactive floors , or interactive floor projection you can find some companies who provide such a thing

Thanks in advance ( and sorry for my damn poor english , français could be better :D )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking into cinder and openframeworks. these are two great libraries that help speed up this kind of stuff. openframeworks works well with opencv (intel's open computer vision library) which makes tracking much easier

of:
http://www.openframeworks.cc/

http://www.aliak.com/content/openframeworks-opencv-computer-vision-libraries

cinder:
http://libcinder.org/

I would recommend these over AS/Flash because C is much faster than flash. Alternatively there is also processing, which is also quite fast.

hope this helps. GL

Comment: Thanks now i just find openframeworks awsome , cause of their great community , thank you sir , you save my a$$ :)

Answer (score 1):

I've just found additional resources might be helpful so i post it maybe someone find it useful i've just choose openframeworks and cider as main libs and resources for my purpose
Special Thanks To Daniel

http://www.tuio.org/

this api works well under several languages for touchscreen implementing and track motion

C++ , Java , C# , Processing , Pure Data , Max/MSP , Quartz Composer ,Flash AS3

----- and

nuicode.com

And there is some useful modules for nui ,  like object tracking module and hand tracking module both works well and useful